# Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string | ParsedUrlQueryInput | null | undefined' Next.js and Typescript

Tags: typescript, next.js

I am trying to pass an array of string from one page to another in Next.js using `<Link href={{ pathname: "/model", query: data }}>`, however the `query` was red underlined:

```js
Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string | ParsedUrlQueryInput | null | undefined'.
Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'ParsedUrlQueryInput'.
Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type 'string[]'.ts(2322)
```

`data` only need to be transmitted from one page to a button component and pass to another page instead of global use, should I use `useContext` to fix this bug? or convert the string array into string using `array.toString()`, and convert back to array afterwards? or any suggestion can provide?

Comment: It sounds like you should probably just be converting that into the expected format (`ParsedUrlQueryInput`) assuming you still want to do it via the query string.

Comment: actually, I don't prefer to do it via the query string, cause it will make the URL very long, the length of the string array is around 10-15 @DBS

Answer (score 0):

The `query` property doesn't accept an array of strings. You must either pass a string or an object.

You can pass the array of strings under a specific querystring:

```
<Link href={{ pathname: "/model", query: { data } }}>
```

Then on your next page use use the `useRouter` hook to get the querystring named `data`.

Comment: when I try it like this: `query: {data: string[]}`, it appear the url become: `/model?data=test1&data=test2`, I can only get `test1` but not `test2` also through `useRouter`

Comment: How are you accessing the querystring? It should be something like `const { query: { data } } = useRouter()`, if I'm not mistaken